# Getting rid of inadvertent "actionPerformed: code in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

When I create event-handling code for a component on a form, it shows up with grayed-background lines and a "do not edit" warning.  They don't need to post the warning, because the code cannot be edited! However, I may (and have) goof by accidentally double-clicking a component, which inserts `actionPerformed` code in my `main.java` file.

I find that that grayed portion of the `actionPerformed` code can't be moved or deleted. Is there a secret ritual by which I can eliminate or move such code blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go back into the form editor and simply delete the "xxxActionPerformed" out of the text box (in the list of possible event handlers).

Explained in slightly more detail [here](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic3373.html)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the ticket. I actually wish I could move these protected blocks around, just to improve the logical flow of my code, but I'll settle for the fact that I don't have to work out the whole event listener process.